# JFrame compiler errors

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, derby

I am getting compiler errors. I have been trying to resolve this a couple of hours but due to my suckyness i have failed. I have higlighted the spot where the errors are in **bold**. It's in the JFrame, not in the class.

This is the class

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author dsfsf
 */
public class Ärende {
    private String kategori;
    private String budgeteradtid;
    private String status;
    private String kommentar;

    public String getKategori() {
        return kategori;
    }

    public void setKategori(String kategori) {
        this.kategori = kategori;
    }

    public String getbudgeteradtid() {
        return budgeteradtid;
    }

    public void setbudgeteradtid(String budgeteradtid) {
        this.budgeteradtid = budgeteradtid;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setstatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

     public String getKommentar() {
        return kommentar;
    }

    public void setKommentar(String kommentar) {
        this.kommentar = kommentar;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.kategori + "     Kategori:     " + this.budgeteradtid + "     Budgeterad tid:     " + this.status + "     Status:     " + 
                "     Kommentar:     " + this.kommentar;

    }
    public String addÄrende() throws SQLException {
        //konrollera status på SQL-exekveringen
        String sRet = "failure";
        Connection cn = null;
        try{
            //Laddar db-library (derby) till applikationens minne
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            //specificerar uppgifter som behövs för att koppla upp sig mot databasen
            cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/COURSE_STUD;create=true;user=course_user;password=pwd");            
            //Kontrollera uppkoppling mot db
            if (cn == null){
                throw new SQLException("Uppkoppling mot databas saknas!");
            }
            //specificerar vilket SQL-uttryck som ska köras mot db
            PreparedStatement stmt = cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ärende (kategori,budgeteradtid,status,kommentar)"
                            + "VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
            stmt.setString(1, getKategori());
            stmt.setString(2, getbudgeteradtid());
            stmt.setString(3, getStatus());
            stmt.setString(4, getKommentar());
            //Kör SQL-uttryck
            int i = stmt.executeUpdate();
            //Kontrollera resultat av SQL-uttryck
            if (i > 0) 
                sRet = "success";
            return sRet; //returnera status från SQL-exekvering
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            throw new SQLException("Problem med db:" + ex.getMessage());
        }finally{
            if (cn!=null) 
                cn.close();
        }
    }
    public ArrayList<Ärende> getÄrende() throws SQLException{
        //Läs in information om db-uppkoppling
        Connection cn = null;
        //håller en lista med ett student-objekt för varje post i db
        ArrayList ärendeList = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            //Laddar db-library (derby) till applikationens minne
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            //specificerar uppgifter som behövs för att koppla upp sig mot databasen
            cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Fiktivt_AB;create=true;user=fiktivt;password=fiktivt"); 
            //Kontrollera uppkoppling mot db
            if (cn == null){
                throw new SQLException("Uppkoppling mot databas saknas!");
            }
            PreparedStatement stmt = cn.prepareStatement("SELECT kategori,budgeteradtid,status, kommentar FROM ärende "
                            + "WHERE ärendeid = ?");

            //Kör SQL-uttryck och ladda upp posterna i ResultSet variabel rs 
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            //Ladda lista med data från ResultSet (rs)
            while (rs.next()){
                //För varje post i db skapas ett student-objekt
                Ärende s = new Ärende();
                s.setKategori(rs.getString("kategori"));
                s.setbudgeteradtid(rs.getString("budgeteradtid"));
                s.setstatus(rs.getString("status"));
                 s.setKommentar(rs.getString("kommentar"));
                //Lägg till student-objekt i arraylist
                ärendeList.add(s);
            }
            return ärendeList;
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            throw new SQLException("Problem med db:" + ex.getMessage());
        }finally{
            if (cn!=null) 
                cn.close();
        }

    }
}
```

This is the JFrame code

```
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


/**
 *
 * @author lrofke
 */
public class JFrameFormTest extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();

    /**
     * Creates new form JFrameFormTest
     */
    public JFrameFormTest() {
        initComponents();
        initÄrendeList();
    }

    private void initÄrendeList(){
        **lstÄrende**.setModel(listModel);
        //Töm lista
        listModel.clear();
        //Ladda listan med poster från db
        Ärende s = new Ärende();
        //Hämta lista med studenter
        ArrayList <Ärende> ärendeList;
        try {
            ärendeList = s.getÄrende();
            //Ladda lista med studenter
            for (Ärende st : ärendeList){
                listModel.addElement(st.toString());
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "FEL! " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        //Justera om "tabort"-knappen ska vara tillgänglig
        int index = listModel.getSize();
        if (index > 0){ //enable delete .
            btnDelete.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtKategori = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtBudgeteradTid = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        javax.swing.JTextField txtStatus = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        btnAdd = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtKommentar = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        lstStudents = new javax.swing.JList();
        btnDelete = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Student"));

        jLabel1.setText("Kategori:");

        txtKategori.setText("Kategori");
        txtKategori.setName(""); // NOI18N
        txtKategori.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtKategoriActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel2.setText("Budgeterad tid:");

        txtBudgeteradTid.setText("Budgeterad tid");
        txtBudgeteradTid.setToolTipText("");
        txtBudgeteradTid.setName(""); // NOI18N

        jLabel3.setText("Status");

        txtStatus.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.LEFT);
        txtStatus.setText("Status");
        txtStatus.setName(""); // NOI18N
        txtStatus.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtStatusActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnAdd.setText("Lägg till ärende");
        btnAdd.setToolTipText("");
        btnAdd.setName(""); // NOI18N
        btnAdd.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnAddActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel4.setText("Kommentar");

        txtKommentar.setText("Ange kommentar");
        txtKommentar.setToolTipText("");
        txtKommentar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtKommentarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(txtKategori, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 76, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(txtStatus))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(btnAdd, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 120, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(txtBudgeteradTid, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 139, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addComponent(txtKommentar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 97, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
        );

        jPanel1Layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {btnAdd, txtBudgeteradTid});

        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(txtKategori, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(txtBudgeteradTid, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(txtStatus, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnAdd))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(txtKommentar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(0, 14, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        txtKategori.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("");

        jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Objektorienterad programutveckling"));

        lstStudents.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
            String[] strings = { " " };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        lstStudents.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        lstStudents.setName("lstStudents"); // NOI18N
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(lstStudents);

        btnDelete.setText("Ta bort");
        btnDelete.setEnabled(false);
        btnDelete.setName("btnRemove"); // NOI18N
        btnDelete.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnDeleteActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton1.setText("Starta webapp");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(btnDelete)
                    .addComponent(jButton1))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 112, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(btnDelete)
                        .addGap(84, 84, 84)
                        .addComponent(jButton1)))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 164, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        //Skapa nytt student-objekt och 
        //läs in värdena från resp. textbox i JFrame-dialogen
        Ärende s = new Ärende();
        s.setKategori(txtKategori.getText());
        s.setbudgeteradtid(txtBudgeteradTid.getText());
        s.setStatus(txtStatus.**getText**());

        try {    
          //Anropa metod för att lägga till student
            if (s.addÄrende().equals("success")){
                //Ladda listan med studenter från db
                initÄrendeList();
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Kunde inte lägga till student!");
            }
        } catch (SQLException | HeadlessException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "FEL! " + ex.getMessage());
        }

    }                                      

    private void txtKategoriActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void btnDeleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Funktion ej implementerad!", "Meddelande", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }                                         

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        //Öppna webbläsaren med den webbapplikation ni utvecklat
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/D0007NJSFWebAppEx/";
        try {
            java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(url));

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "FEL! " + ex.getMessage());
         }  

    }                                        

    private void txtKommentarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                            

    private void txtStatusActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameFormTest.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameFormTest.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameFormTest.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameFormTest.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JFrameFormTest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnAdd;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnDelete;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JList lstStudents;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtBudgeteradTid;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtKategori;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtKommentar;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`txtStatus` is declared as a local variable `javax.swing.JTextField txtStatus = new javax.swing.JTextField();` and will not be accessible outside of the `initComponents` method

`lstÄrende` not declared at all and is undefined

You can modify `txtStatus` defination via the Netbeans properties sheet, "Code" sheet

Select the field in the form editor, click "Code" in the property sheet and unselect the "Use Local Variable" property

[image: NB Properties Sheet]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the bolded parts and i'm kind of out of time to read the whole code, but some things to consider :

- I strongly suggest you don't use the GUI Editor with GroupLayout. I know it's handy at first, you can drag and drop items and place them as you wish, but it really gets out of control **very** quickly. Take a look at MigLayout, which is really nice and easy to learn/maintain.
- Try not using special characters in your method / fields names (like Ärende, just write Arende, Aerende or however you wish)